# Javascript: using a for statement as a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, for-loop

I'm fairly new to javascript and something I've been playing with lately is the 'for' statement. I'm questioning one thing, though. I've learned how to make a 'for' statement do things as if it was an output, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
console.log(i);
}
```

But what if you want to set a variable for the whole output of the 'for' statement?

```
var destinationArray = ["town", "areas", "bosses"];
var destinationArraySet = 1;
var i;

for ( i = 0; i < destinationArraySet; i++) {
console.log(destinationArray[i]);
} /*the whole thing should be equal to var destination */


var userDestinationPrompt = ("Where would you like to go? Available places: " +
    /* var destination */
    +
    ".").toUpperCase();
```

To give some more context: I'm making a game that allows further destinations when the destination before is cleared. Once that's achieved, I set destinationArraySet to a higher value, which means that more places would be logged and put after 'Available places'.

Help would be very appreciated! If there's something not clear enough let me know.

Comment: The `for` statement doesn't have an "output", it's not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var destination = '';
var destinationArray = ["town", "areas", "bosses"];
var destinationArraySet = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < destinationArraySet; i++) {
    destination += destinationArray[i] + '\n';
}
console.log(destination);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` statement is not an expression, so it doesn't have a return value. Use a variable to collect values in the loop:

```
var destination = '';
for (var i = 0; i < destinationArraySet; i++) {
  destination += destinationArray[i] + ' ';
}
```

Of course, if you only want to concatenate the values in part of an array, you can use the `slice` method to get part of it, then the `join` method:

```
var destination = destinationArray.slice(0, destinationArraySet).join(' ');
```

Comment: `destinationArraySet` is a number, so you can't use the `length` property on it.

Comment: I don't know yet how the slice and join methods work yet, but I'll keep it in mind if I want to build a system like this in the future. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The for statement doesn't have an "output", it's not a function. Thinking `for` as a function will give you troubles later on. `for` is simply a statement that continuously execute the block of code inside. It does not "output", or in other words, return any value.

Do this instead:

```
var destinationArray = ["town", "areas", "bosses"], destinationArraySet = 1;

var userDestinationPrompt = ("Where would you like to go? Available places: " +
    destinationArray.slice(0, destinationArraySet).join("\n")
+ ".").toUpperCase();

prompt(userDestinationPrompt);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7c2b9q7m/1/

- `destinationArray.slice(0, destinationArraySet)`: Cuts the array to the specified length.
- `.join("\n")`: Join the newly created array by `\n`s (newline) to micic the default `console.log` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var destinationArray = ["town", "areas", "bosses"];
var destinationArraySet = 1;
var i;
var availablePlaces = '';
var separator = '';

for ( i = 0; i < destinationArraySet; i++) {
   availablePlaces += separator + destinationArray[i];
   separator = ', ';
} 


var userDestinationPrompt = ("Where would you like to go? Available places: " +
    availablePlaces + ".").toUpperCase();
```